# Error while updating Android Studio 3.0 to 3.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3

[image]

I got this dialogue while updating Android Studio.How to resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should download a clean installation of Android Studio, install it and uninstall the old version.